# How to do a virus scan on multiple users?

Tags: anti-virus, multiple-users

I would really like to know how I can run my virus scanner so it scans multiple accounts.

How do I configure this?

Comment: Google translate Dutch->English: "An equivalent of comprehensive virus check on all users." "Let me know how I can run a virus scanner that checks all users equal. How do I set this in /"

Comment: Dutch guy translates Dutch->English: "I would like to know how I can run a virusscanner that simultaneously checks all users. How do I configure this?"

Comment: I stil don't understand the question though. @aircraft: "wat bedoelt u met 'gelijk alle gebruikers nagaan'?

Comment: Welkom op Super User, wij zijn een engelstalige site. Gelieve in het Engels te communiceren zodat iedereen begrijpt waar je het over hebt, bij voorbaat dank... :-)

Comment: @TomWij Haha, ik heb de vraag maar even vertaald ;)

Comment: Oh, ik was er ook mee bezig... Is inderdaad handig. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you do full system scan as an administrator, every account will be scanned.

> **Dutch**: Als je het programma als administrator draait, dan zal elk account worden gescand.